# Google API Javascript Login - Check if User Image Is Default

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-plus, google-authentication

How can I check if the user has the default image (eg. `image.isDefault` result) when logging someone in through the Google API. I'm using [getBasicProfile()](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#googleusergetbasicprofile) to retrieve the `id`, `name`, `email`, `imageUrl`... etc.

[Code source](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/build-button#building_a_button_with_a_custom_graphic)

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api:client.js"></script>
  <script>
  var googleUser = {};
  var startApp = function() {
    gapi.load('auth2', function(){
      auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
        client_id: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
        // Request scopes in addition to 'profile' and 'email'
        //scope: 'additional_scope'
      });
      attachSignin(document.getElementById('customBtn'));
    });
  };

  function attachSignin(element) {
    console.log(element.id);
    auth2.attachClickHandler(element, {},
        function(googleUser) {

        var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();

        var response = {};
        response.id =           profile.getId();
        response.name =         profile.getName();
        response.first_name =   profile.getGivenName();
        response.last_name =    profile.getFamilyName();
        response.image_url =    profile.getImageUrl();
        response.email =        profile.getEmail();
        console.log(response);

        //******* HOW TO GET THE "image.isDefault" RESULT? ******


        }, function(error) {
          alert(JSON.stringify(error, undefined, 2));
        });
  }
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="gSignInWrapper">
    <span class="label">Sign in with:</span>
    <div id="customBtn" class="customGPlusSignIn">
      <span class="icon"></span>
      <span class="buttonText">Google</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="name"></div>
  <script>startApp();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the object I'm looking for:

```
ageRange: Object
    min: 21
circledByCount: 0
displayName: "John Smith"
etag: ""FT7asdjf83294289sf/sh-UjzBIkCHasfdj283429sf""
id: "1127384729842983928"
image:
    isDefault: true
    url: "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-XYuefSD/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/23visd238/photo.jpg?sz=50"
isPlusUser: true
kind: "plus#person"
language: "en"
name:
    familyName: "Smith"
    givenName: "John"
objectType: "person"
url: "https://plus.google.com/118948298492849237"
verified: false
```

Comment: It only return the default image

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer:

```
var googleUser = {};

//This method sets up the sign-in listener after the client library loads.
var startApp = function() {
    gapi.load('auth2', function(){
        gapi.client.load('plus','v1').then(function() {

            // Retrieve the singleton for the GoogleAuth library and set up the client.
            auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
                client_id: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com',
                cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin'
                //scope: 'additional_scope'
            });

            attachSignin(document.getElementById('custom-google-btn'));
        });

    });
};


function attachSignin(element) {

    auth2.attachClickHandler(element, {},

        function(googleUser) {

            var authResult = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
            if (authResult.isSignedIn.get()) {

                gapi.client.plus.people.get({
                    'userId': 'me'
                }).then(function(res) {

                    var profile = res.result;
                    console.log(profile);
                    //******All the image data is available here******
                    console.log(profile.image.isDefault);

                });

            } else {

                //alert('not signed in');
                if (authResult['error'] || authResult.currentUser.get().getAuthResponse() == null) {
                    // There was an error, which means the user is not signed in.
                    // As an example, you can handle by writing to the console:
                    console.log('There was an error: ' + authResult['error']);
                }

            }

        }, function(error) {
            //alert(JSON.stringify(error, undefined, 2));
        });
}
```